# Trying to print characters in files but printing blanks instead

Tags: c

Here is a small method I have:

```
void CompareTwoFiles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2){

char ch1, ch2;
int flag = 0;
//must seek first to determine the sizes
fseek (fp1, 0, SEEK_END);
fseek (fp2, 0, SEEK_END);
if(ftell(fp1) != ftell(fp2)){
    printf("The sizes of the files are different so they cannot be equal.\n");
    return;
}
while (((ch1 = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) &&((ch2 = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF))
{
    /*
      * character by character comparision
      * if equal then continue by comparing till the end of the files
      */
    if (ch1 == ch2)
    {
        flag = 1;
        continue;
    }     
    //If not equal then return the byte position         
    else
    {
        fseek(fp1, -1, SEEK_CUR);        
        flag = 0;
        break;
    }
}

if (flag == 0)
{
    printf("Two files are not equal :  byte position at which two files differ is %d.\n", ftell(fp1)+1);
    printf("First file contains %c and second file contains %c \n", ch1, ch2); //ISSUE: prints blank for ch1 and ch2
}
else
{
    printf("Two files are Equal\n ", ftell(fp1)+1);
}

}
```

I would simple like to print the two chars that I assign with fgetc in my printf. But instead I am getting blanks. The output looks like this:

First file contains  and second file contains

Could someone please point out what I'm going wrong. I'm a little rusty with C and C++.

Comment: Fyi, you're not rewinding your files after seeking to their ends for length calculation.

Comment: Standard reminder: When in doubt, put in some extra printouts so you can see whast the program is actually doing. Or run it under a debugger, which lets you step through it line by line while watching the variables change.

Comment: @WhozCraig would you mind elaborating? I googled rewinding files and it seems like it's some sort of substitute for fseek but most people seem to say that it's better to use fseek. Is there something I should add at the end?

Comment: @aurora91 The first thing you do is fseek to the end of the file. So the next thing you're going to `fgetc` is guaranteed to be EOF because ... you're at the end of the file. So you need to rewind/fseek back to the beginning.

Comment: @kfsone. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix warnings first.

```
$ gcc main.c 
main.c: In function ‘CompareTwoFiles’:
main.c:37:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Two files are not equal :  byte position at which two files differ 
            ^
main.c:42:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     printf("Two files are Equal\n ", ftell(fp1)+1);
```

Get a clean compile and just rewind the files, you see your code works. Your code didn't rewind, so you didn't know which `char` you got.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void CompareTwoFiles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2) {

    char ch1, ch2;
    int flag = 0;
//must seek first to determine the sizes
    fseek(fp1, 0, SEEK_END);
    fseek(fp2, 0, SEEK_END);
    if (ftell(fp1) != ftell(fp2)) {
        printf("The sizes of the files are different so they cannot be equal.\n");
        return;
    }
    rewind(fp1);
    rewind(fp2);
    while (((ch1 = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) && ((ch2 = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)) {
        /*
          * character by character comparision
          * if equal then continue by comparing till the end of the files
          */
        if (ch1 == ch2) {
            flag = 1;
            continue;
        }
            //If not equal then return the byte position
        else {
            fseek(fp1, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("Two files are not equal :  byte position at which two files differ is %d.\n", (int) ftell(fp1) + 1);
        printf("First file contains %c and second file contains %c \n", ch1, ch2); //ISSUE: prints blank for ch1 and ch2
    }
    else {
        printf("Two files are Equal %d\n ", (int) ftell(fp1) + 1);
    }

}


int main() {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("tmp.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen("tmp2.txt", "r");

    CompareTwoFiles(fp, fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

**tmp.txt**

> 1 1 23 2134   123 12321
>
> 123
>
> 42

**tmp2.txt**

> 0 1 23 2134   123 12321
>
> 123
>
> 42

**Output**

```
$ ./a.out 
Two files are not equal :  byte position at which two files differ is 1.
First file contains 1 and second file contains 0
```

Comment: Would +1 if there was an attempt at explaining what the OP was doing wrong, if not just comments where the rewinds are.

Comment: `ftell()` returns `long`.  Better to use `printf("Two files are Equal %ld\n ",  ftell(fp1) + 1);`. than to narrow the result with a downcast.